# django custom admin pages

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like my model has multiple `list view` endpoints in django admin.

For instance, I'd like to view `all the blogs with more than 5 comments`
`all the blogs that has been shared`

How do you make multiple endpoints in django admin? (basically multiple querysets for one model class)

Sure I can use something like https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus but It would take many hours to create the templates...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create several [proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#proxy-models):

```
class SharedBlog(Blog):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = 'shared blog'
```

And override the `get_queryset()` method of the `ModelAdmin`:

```
class SharedBlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(SharedBlogAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(shared=True)

admin.site.register(SharedBlog, SharedBlogAdmin)
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I've used this method many times in the past. It's the fastest way I've found to add additional list-views.

Comment: btw, Is there a way to pass parameter to admin powered pages? so that you can query using the passed-in params.

Comment: You can pass any GET parameter you want.  Almost all `ModelAdmin` methods have the `request` as one of the arguments so you can obtain parameters from the `request.GET` dictionary.